# Take the value of a custom field service

Tags: whmcs

I created a custom field called `Chave`. It appears on the PRODUCTS / SERVICES screen.

[image]

I need to get theVALUE from the `Chave field`, inside the clientssumary.tpl file.

I tried it this way:

```
{php}
   echo $params['customfields']["Chave"];
{/php}
```

But it doesn't capture the value.

How to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: What is content of `$params`? Do `var_dump($params);exit;` (or without `exit;`) to check.

Comment: @Tpojka It didn't print anything, I thought that was how it was done, because in a hook file I use that parameter. Do you know which parameter to use?

Comment: I am not using `whmcs`. I just tried to help with debugging.